# Power BI Matrix is missing Conditional Formatting

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I was watching this video and at the minute [2:00](https://youtu.be/wP5UhQQHKrg?t=120) you can see how the Power BI Matrix has the Conditional Formatting option.

But when I look at my Matrix I don't see this option:

[image]

And yes, I'm targeting a Matrix and I cannot see it anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under cell elements.

[image]

PBI is updated every month and the UI moves around a lot.